# Oracle Apex Align Items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a static content with several items:

[image]

I would like to align my items as follows:

- File Browser not stretched with certain size
- Text Area below File Browser
- Both buttons below File Browser and Text Area
- All items centered inside the static content

Something like this:
[image]

I have tried different combinations with column and column span but the items are just chaotic.
How to align the items without to stretch them and centered?

Edit:

Here is a simplified example of my app:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4000:1:107157186133226::NO:RP:FB_FLOW_ID,F4000_P1_FLOW,P0_FLOWPAGE,RECENT_PAGES:107375,107375,107375

workspace:test07032022

User:demo07

PW:sodemo07032022

Comment: Screenshot shows what you have, right? Edit it (in any appropriate application) to show what would you like to get as a result. Also, it would probably be simpler (for us) if you created sample page on apex.oracle.com, shared login credentials so that we could copy that page to another and fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added an example.

Comment: That's page we can only view, not edit. Besides, you didn't show desired result so ... it is kind of difficult to blindly guess what settings you should set to get something we should only imagine.

Comment: I hope it's working now (sorry I share for first time). I added an image how it should look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for login info; Apex required me to change initial password so I did it; new password is **sodemo07032022** (I edited your message to reflect it for other people who'd want to take a look).

---

I copied your page 2 to page **3** and did some modifications; the result is this:

[image]

What did I do?

- set items to start at column 4 and span 4 columns
- modified text area's width (was 30, now is 60 characters)
- modified file browse item's "display as" property
- moved buttons to region body; fixed where to start and how many columns to span; set their width in "Custom attributes" property; modified template options (set the type)

See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed the page to look much better now!